# melting data.frame in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe in R in the format below

```
      name1    name2    name3
word1  1         0        1
word2  0         1        1
word3  1         1        0
```

I would like to melt this dataframe into:

```
name1 |word1|word3
name2 |word2|word3
name3 |word1|word2
```

Comment: [A reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) is an essential question element. Demonstrated effort is nice, too.

Comment: You also need to describe how the result should be derived from the input. I have no idea, why it has 2 columns with "words".

Comment: So basically, in the dataframe, "words" are the first column, the "names" are for columns 2,3,4. Usually the function melt in the reshape2 package will melt this dataframe into 3 columns. But, what I am looking for is to have the columnames "names" in the first column, and all the other "words" one in each column according to their relationship with the names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a one-liner, base solution:

```
out <- t(apply(mydf, 2, function(x) row.names(mydf)[which(as.logical(x))]))
```

The result is a matrix:

```
> out
      [,1]    [,2]   
name1 "word1" "word3"
name2 "word2" "word3"
name3 "word1" "word2"
```

which is easily made into a dataframe:

```
> as.data.frame(out)
         V1    V2
name1 word1 word3
name2 word2 word3
name3 word1 word2
```

Here's your data as I read it in:

```
mydf <- read.table(text='      name1    name2    name3
word1  1         0        1
word2  0         1        1
word3  1         1        0', header=TRUE)
```